# How to avoid duplicated data cache on range query?

Tags: sql, caching, memcached

everyone. 
Our rest API supported a ranged resource query like this: `/api/v1/examples?offset=0&limit=100`.
We cached every query on memcached to improve performance. But, two query may have duplicated data range.

For example:
`/api/v1/examples?offset=0&limit=100`
`/api/v1/examples?offset=1&limit=101`

Data in range 2~100 will be cached twice!!
Is there any method to avoid this?